# play movie file during iphone application startup(i.e during application loading)

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

I want to play a movie file or any animation file till the time application not loaded completely.
Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Did you find a workable answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to think carefully about if you really want to do this. On a hardware limited device, loading a movie is going to increase load times, not reduce them as should be your goal. Even the Default.png method is meant as a way to indicate the application is loading and reduce the perceived load time to the user; it's not intended as a splash screen or eye candy.

If your application does have a very long operation during load that you absolutely can't avoid before showing a functional UI, I think the best bet might be to whip up a quick 'loading' animation using Core Animation layers. Maybe there's a better way to do it but in my experience loading the movie player takes time.

Comment: While I agree with your point here, this is a poor answer since you are trying to talk the OP out of a solution instead of answering his question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean.

The iPhone shows a still image (Default.png) while the application loads, prior to your code getting any control.

Once your code has control, you can use MPMoviePlayer to play a video. You could launch a separate thread to do whatever takes so long that you want to hide it behind a video...

Answer (score -1):

The only way to play a movie is to use the MPMoviePlayer. This takes over the UI and is full screen -- none of your app will show through until the movie is closed.

While it sounds cool to have a movie play while the app is loading, on the iPhone, it's really not practical. This is not something you want to do.