# Does Simulator Play Video?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, simulator

I want To Add an splash screen on my application which will play a video. Can I test it on simulator?  Any help regarding playing the video will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342383/play-movie-file-during-iphone-application-startupi-e-during-application-loading) and [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3136-play-intro-movie-splash-screen.html) might help you...Simulator does play video..But I dont think you can play video as splash screen..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html tag(video) then it will not be shown on simulator.But on device its okay.

You want to show a video as a splash screen,i dont know how you managed that.

Better you could use a gif file.